# Afnetworking how to dealloc downloaded data memory?

Tags: ios, memory-management, afnetworking-2

I'm downloading 40 mb of file with post request. During download request it allocates 40 mb too. But after that when download complated memory not dealloceting itself. Here is my sample code, how can release memory?

```
+(AFHTTPRequestOperation*)PostDownloadRequest:(NSDictionary*)postDic saveName:(Product*)product Url:(NSString*)Url success:(void (^)(id responseObject)) success failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation)) failure
{
    if(Downloadings==nil)
    {
        Downloadings=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    __block AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Application/Json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setCachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    if([IdentityUser UserId]!=nil)
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[IdentityUser Token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    if (product.productFormatType == 1) {
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Application/pdf" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    }
    else{
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Application/zip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    }
    [Downloadings addObject:product.iosInAppId];

    __block AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation =[manager POST:Url
                                                         parameters:postDic
                                                            success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                                                dispatch_queue_t taskQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
                                                                 dispatch_async(taskQ, ^{
                                                                    FileProcess *pr=[[FileProcess alloc]init];
                                                                    NSLog(@"%d", (int)product.productFormatType);
                                                                    if (product.productFormatType == 1) {
                                                                        [pr SavePdfToFile:product data:responseObject];
                                                                    }
                                                                    else{
                                                                        [pr SaveEpubToFile:product data:responseObject];
                                                                    }
                                                                });
                                                                  success(nil);
                                                                responseObject=nil;
                                                                requestOperation=nil;
                                                            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                failure(operation);
                                                            }];

    return requestOperation;
}
```

Comment: what the purpose of `__block` before `requestOperation` ?

Comment: i thought it can be because of requestOperation object so tried to set nil in success which is in other thread. because of that i used __block

Comment: as for me all three lines with `=nil` not required, and `__block` can be removed too

Comment: i agree with you. arc should do all of this but i tried these too. can it be because of method is static(+)? i write below, when i set requestOperation as nil in returned class when operation complated, it reduced a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Place your code inside

```
@autoreleasepool {
    ...do your work here...
  }
```

Try this :

> ```
> @autoreleasepool 
> {
>     if (product.productFormatType == 1) 
>          [pr SavePdfToFile:product data:responseObject];
>     else
>          [pr SaveEpubToFile:product data:responseObject];
> }
> ```

Comment: this is also not the way. but i set nil 'requestOperation' object in other class that fixed a bit. App starts with 8 mb of usage. than with download it increases to 50 mb while downloading. Now i set nil, it decreases to 15-20 mb.